# How to redirect old site URL to new Symfony 4 application URL using htaccess file?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I am in the process of migrating a static website to Symfony 4. I would like to redirect the old URLs to their corresponding routes in the new Symfony 4 app (while keeping the same domain name), like so:

https://www.old-site-url.com/contact.html to https://www.old-site-url.com/contact

I have tried specifying a redirect rule in the htaccess (located in the project root) :

`RewriteRule https://www.old-site-url.com/contact.html$ https://beta.old-site-url.com/about [R=301,L]`

Note: I redirect one URL to the beta subdomain during the testing phase.

However the redirections still wouldn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot match `HOST_NAME` in `RewriteRule`. You must use a `RewriteCond` for that like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?old-site-url\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ https://beta.old-site-url.com/contact [R=301,L,NC]
```